# best code in java for projecteuler#59

Tags: java

Please help me to understand this code or suggest a different method in java for this problem 59 on project euler
https://projecteuler.net/problem=59,please give me suggestions it will be really helpful as i have been spending a lot of time on this code..
here is the code:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/Users/MA/Desktop/p059_cipher.txt")));
        int message[];
        String s = br.readLine();
        String str[] = new String[9999];
        str = s.split(",");
        message = new int[str.length];
        int res;
        String key = "";

        int temp[] = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            message[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);

        int max = -1;
        int l = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < 123; z++)
            temp[z] = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            max = -1;
            for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
                for (int j = k; j < message.length; j += 3) {
                    res = message[j] ^ i;
                    System.out.println(res);
                    temp[res]++;
                }
            }

            for (int z = 97; z < 123; z++) {
                if (max < temp[z]) {
                    max = temp[z];
                    l = z;
                }
            }

            for (int z = 0; z < 123; z++)
                temp[z] = 0;

            char ch = (char) l;
            System.out.println(ch);
            key += ch;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        int z = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            if (k == 0)
                z = 'g';
            else if (k == 1)
                z = 'o';
            else
                z = 'd';

            for (int i = k; i < message.length; i += 3) {
                sum += message[i] ^ z;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: **and What Exactly in this code you are not able to understand ??**

Comment: i can't understand logic behind the code completely....plz explain logic for using temp[];l;how was key found in the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are some quality issues with this code.

It follows the C compatible notation for arrays, with `[]` after the variable rather than after the type, which is conventional in java.

```
    String str[] = new String[9999];
    str = s.split(",");
```

should be

```
    String[] str = s.split(",");
```

And

```
   int temp[] = new int[1000];
```

probably

```
   int temp[] = new int[123];
```

It more seems a bit of code for review purposes. Not much happens. Xor-ing with "god" is a bit tasteless.

`a` has ASCII code 97 and `z` 123.
*Pick something more interesting.*

---

***Reorganized code for better reading:***

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String line = readFirstLineOfFile();
    int[] message = numbersFormLine(line);

    String key = "";

    int temp[] = new int[1000];

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
            for (int j = k; j < message.length; j += 3) {
                int res = message[j] ^ i;
                System.out.println(res);
                temp[res]++;
            }
        }

        // Determine most frequent letter of this k:
        int mostFrequentLetter = 0;
        int max = -1;
        for (int z = 97; z < 123; z++) {
            if (max < temp[z]) {
                max = temp[z];
                mostFrequentLetter  = z;
            }
        }

        // Clear again for next loop:
        for (int z = 0; z < 123; z++)
            temp[z] = 0;

        char ch = (char) mostFrequentLetter;
        System.out.println(ch);
        key += ch;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        int z = "god".charAt(k);

        for (int i = k; i < message.length; i += 3) {
            sum += message[i] ^ z;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

with help methods:

```
private String readFirstLineOfFile() throws IOException {
    Path file = Paths.get(("C:/Users/MA/Desktop/p059_cipher.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        return br.readLine();
    } // Always closes file.
}

private int[] numbersFromLine(String line) {
    String[] str = line.split(",");
    int[] message = new int[str.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        message[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
    }
    return message;
}
```

***Partial explanation:***

The array temp is a letter "frequency" table. The index is the letter, and one sees that the index `l` (=letter) is sought for which the frequency is maximal (`max`).

"god" seems to be the mentioned password. `k` loops 3 times, maybe the password length?

I am not entirely willing to calculate the exact functioning. A solution in another language might prove more explanatory.

Comment: this code is solution to the question in the link provided..i would like to know the solution to that question in java.

Comment: how can we say that most frequent letter of a specific k is part of the key?

Comment: how can we say that most frequent letter of a specific k is part of the key?